# has someone have an idea how to implement sound to my racing?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I´m almost done with my racing game but somehow I can't implement music to it. I already tried it with an  tag, a sound variable in javascript and I tried download howler which is a audio library.
Does someone have an idea how to construct a code which plays audio for my app I would be very help full because it would finish my app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>3D Car Drive</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
    </head>
    <style>
                  body{
                margin:0;
                height:100vh;
                width:100vw;
            }
            
            #mainContainer {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                transform-origin:0% 0%;
                width:100%;
                transform:  translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            #city {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                height:30vw;
                width:100%;
                z-index:-1;
                display: block;
            }
            
            #myCanvas {
                background:transparent;
                z-index: 100;
            }
            
            .aImg {
                display:none;
            }
            
            #mainContainer {
                display:none;
            }
            
            #scoreDiv {
                position:absolute;
                right:0;
                background:transparent;
                display:inline-block;
                border:3px solid red;
                padding:3px 50px 3px 10px;
                border-radius:20px;
                font-weight:700;
                font-size:24px;
                height:30px;
                margin:10px;
                z-index:1000;
                transform-origin:100% 0%;
            }
            
            #cn {
                height:52px;
                width:52px;
                background:red;
                position:absolute;
                right:-8px;
                top:-8px;
                border-radius:50%;
            }
            
            .gameHome {
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                background:#fff;
                height:100vh;
                width:100vw;
                transform-origin:0% 0%;
                text-align:center;
            }
            
            #gameTitle {
                text-align:center;
                font-family:cursive;
                font-size:35px;
                margin-top:50px;
                font-weight:800;
            }
            
            #playBtn {
                font-size:20px;
                display:inline-block;
                background:#1642ea;
                color:#fff;
                padding:3px 25px;
                margin-top: 100px;
                border:none;
                border-radius:10px;
                box-shadow:3px 4px #000;
                outline:none;
            }
            
            #gameConf {
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
                background:red;
            }
            
            #gameDifficulty {
                width:100%;
                height:50%;
                background:blue;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            
            .diffOpt {
                background:green
                font-family:cursive;
                font-size:20px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            
            #loading {
                height:60px;
                width:60px;
                background:transparent;
                display:inline-block;
                border:10px solid transparent;
                border-bottom-color:red;
                border-left-color:red;
                border-radius:50%;
                animation:ld 1s linear infinite;
            }
            
            @keyframes ld {
                0% {
                    transform:translateY(-165px) rotate(0deg);
                }
                100% {
                    transform:translateY(-165px) rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
    </style>
    <body onload="done()">
        <div id="scoreDiv">
            <span id="score">0</span>
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jRAp0y/coin.png" id="cn">
        </div>
        <div class="gameHome" id="startPage">
            <div id="gameTitle">3D Car Drive</div>
            <button onclick="ld()" id="playBtn"><span style="font-size:18px">Loading Assets<br>Please Wait...<br>This may take a few seconds for first time</span></button><br>
            <div id="ldc"><div id="loading"></div></div>
            <p>Rotate your phone & tilt left/right or tap left/right side of screen to move the car<br>Use left/right arrow key on your PC</p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function(){
                    "use strict"
                    var hw = window.innerWidth || 360;
                    var hh = window.innerHeight || 560;
                    var gameHome = document.getElementById("startPage");
                    var scoreDiv = document.getElementById("scoreDiv");
                    if(hh > hw){
                        gameHome.style.height = hw+"px";
                        gameHome.style.width = hh+"px";
                        gameHome.style.transform = "translateX("+hw+"px) rotate(90deg)";
                        scoreDiv.style.bottom = 0;
                        scoreDiv.style.transform = "rotate(90deg) translateX(40px)";
                    }
                })();
            </script>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="mainContainer" style="background:#0f0" >
            <img id="city" src="https://image.ibb.co/jCGU0y/cty.jpg">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" style="/*background:#9de732*/" ></canvas>
        </div>
        <img class="aImg" id="t1" src="https://image.ibb.co/dZi5Ly/t1.png">
        <img class="aImg" id="t2" src="https://image.ibb.co/jajjDJ/t2.png">
        <img class="aImg" id="t3" src="https://image.ibb.co/it4jDJ/t5.png">
        <img class="aImg" id="t4" src="https://image.ibb.co/ksy0nd/t4.png">
        <img class="aImg" id="c1" src="https://image.ibb.co/f4v7YJ/c2.png">
        <script>
                   
        var ld;
        var loaded = false;
        
        function done(){
            document.getElementById("ldc").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("ldc").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("playBtn").innerHTML = "PLAY";
            loaded = true;
        }
        
        (function(){
            var w = window.innerWidth || 360;
            var h = window.innerHeight || 560;
        
            if(h > w){
                var nh = h;
                h = w;
                w = nh;
                document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.transform = "translateX("+(h)+"px) rotate(90deg)";
            }
            document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.width = w+"px";
            document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.height = h+"px";
            
            document.getElementById("city").style.height = h*.3+"px";
            document.getElementById("city").style.width = w+"px";
            
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            c.height = h;
            c.width = w;
            
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        
        function loadGame(){
            "use strict";
            
            var roadWidth = 5*w/36;
            var roadTop = h-h*0.7;
            var roadLeft = (w-roadWidth)/2;
            var roadConstant = roadLeft/(h-roadTop);
            var score = 0;
            var scoreC = document.getElementById("score");
            function updateScore(ds){
                score+=ds;
                scoreC.textContent = score;
            }
            updateScore(0);
            
            var rso = [];
            var ratio = 0.8;
            var totalRso = 20;
            var maxHF = h*(1-ratio)/(2.25*(1-Math.pow(ratio,totalRso)));
            var maxH = maxHF;
            var totalHeight = 0.7*h;
            var minWidth = 1;
            var maxWidth = 26;
            var dif = maxWidth - minWidth;
            var changedHeight = totalHeight-maxH*ratio;
            var cnst1 = Math.pow(ratio,totalRso)/(1-ratio);
            var stp = h-totalHeight;
            var tMaxH = h*20/36;
            var treeCnst = tMaxH/roadLeft;
            
            var gameDifficulty = 100;
            
            
            
            function TreeBuilder(src,src2,start,left){
                this.src = treeSrc[src];
                this.src2 = treeSrc[src2];
                this.y = start;
                this.x = 0;
                this.h = 0;
                this.w = 0;
                this.dy = 0.01;
                this.r = 1.009;
                this.left = left;
            }
            
            TreeBuilder.prototype.draw = function(){
                this.y += this.dy;
                this.dy *= this.r;
                this.x = (h-this.y)*roadConstant - this.w - this.w*this.left;
                this.h = (roadLeft-this.x-this.w*this.left)*treeCnst;
                this.w = this.h*2/3;
                
                ctx.drawImage(this.src,this.x,this.y-this.h,this.w,this.h);
                ctx.drawImage(this.src2,w-this.x-this.w,this.y-this.h,this.w,this.h);
            
                if(this.y >= h){
                    this.y = stp;
                    this.h = 0;
                    this.w = 0;
                    this.left = Math.random()*3;
                    this.dy = 0.5;
                }
            }
            
            function _i(x){
                return document.getElementById(x);
            }
            var treeSrc = [_i("t1"),_i("t2"),_i("t3"),_i("t4")];
            
            var trees = [];
            for(var n = 0; n < ((h*0.7)/50-2); n++){
                trees.push(new TreeBuilder(Math.floor(Math.random()*4),Math.floor(Math.random()*4),stp+n*50,2));
            }
            
            
            var carWCnst = roadLeft*2/totalHeight;
            var carW = (w > 560) ? 120 : 90;
            var carH = carW*2/3;
            
            function CarBuilder(src,start,lane){
                this.src = carSrc[src];
                this.y = start;
                this.x = 0;
                this.h = 0;
                this.w = 0;
                this.dy = 0.5;
                this.lane = lane;
            }
            
            CarBuilder.prototype.draw = function(){
                this.dy *= 1.01;
                this.y += this.dy;
                this.x = (carWCnst/2)*(h-this.y)+(w-(carWCnst*(h-this.y)))*this.lane/8;
                this.w = carW-carW*carWCnst*(h-this.y)/w;
                this.h = 1.7*this.w/3;
                
                ctx.drawImage(this.src,this.x,this.y-this.h,this.w,this.h);
                if(this.y >= h-20){
                    if(Math.abs(this.x-cx) <= carH && Math.abs(this.y-h+carH) <= carH){
                        clearInterval(intv);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("startPage").style.display = "block";
                        },1000);
                    }
                }
                if(this.y >= h+100){
                    this.y = stp;
                    this.h = 0;
                    this.w = 0;
                    this.left = Math.random()*3;
                    this.dy = 0.5;
                    this.lane = 1+Math.random()*5;
                }
            }
            
            var carSrc = [_i("c1"),_i("c1"),_i("c1")];
            
            var cars = [];
            for(var n = 0; n < ((h*0.7+100)/gameDifficulty); n++){
                cars.push(new CarBuilder(Math.floor(Math.random()*3),stp+n*gameDifficulty,1));
            }
            
            //Coin.....
            var coinW = (w > 560) ? 75 : 60;
            function CoinBuilder(start,lane){
                this.src = coinSrc;
                this.y = start;
                this.x = 0;
                this.h = 0;
                this.w = 0;
                this.dy = 0.5;
                this.lane = lane;
            }
            
            CoinBuilder.prototype.draw = function(){
                this.dy *= 1.01;
                this.y += this.dy;
                this.x = (carWCnst/2)*(h-this.y)+(w-(carWCnst*(h-this.y)))*this.lane/8;
                this.w = coinW-coinW*carWCnst*(h-this.y)/w;
                this.h = this.w;
                
                ctx.drawImage(this.src,this.x,this.y-this.h,this.w,this.h);
                if(this.y >= h-20){
                    if(Math.abs(this.x-cx) <= coinW && Math.abs(this.y-h+coinW) <= coinW){
                        this.y = stp;
                        this.h = 0;
                        this.w = 0;
                        this.left = Math.random()*3;
                        this.dy = 0.5;
                        this.lane = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*5);
                        updateScore(1);
                    }
                }
                if(this.y >= h+100){
                    this.y = stp;
                    this.h = 0;
                    this.w = 0;
                    this.left = Math.random()*3;
                    this.dy = 0.5;
                    this.lane = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*5);
                }
            }
            
            var coinSrc = _i("cn");
            
            var coins = [];
            for(var n = 0; n < ((h*0.7+100)/(gameDifficulty-50)); n++){
                coins.push(new CoinBuilder(stp+n*(gameDifficulty-50),6));
            }
            
            
            
            //End Coin...
            
            
            
            function rectPoints(n,ho){
                n = totalRso-n-1;
                var y1 = stp+maxH*cnst1*(Math.pow(1/ratio,n)-1);
                var x1 = roadLeft-roadConstant*(y1-stp);
                var y2 = y1;
                var x2 = x1 + minWidth+(y1-stp)*dif/totalHeight;
                var y3 = y1 + maxH*cnst1*(Math.pow(1/ratio,n+1)-1);
                var x3 = roadLeft-roadConstant*(y3-stp);
                var y4 = y3;
                var x4 = x3 + minWidth+(y3-stp)*dif/totalHeight;
                
                return [x1,y1,x2,y2,x4,y4,x3,y3];
            }
            
            
            for(var n = 0; n < totalRso; n++){
                rso.push(rectPoints(n,h));
                rso[n][8] = (n%2==0) ? "#000" : "#fff";
            }
            
            function draw(){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo((w-roadWidth)/2,stp);
                ctx.lineTo((w-roadWidth)/2+roadWidth,stp);
                ctx.lineTo(w,h);
                ctx.lineTo(0,h);
                ctx.fillStyle="#555";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
                for(var n = 0; n < totalRso; n++){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(rso[n][0],rso[n][1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(rso[n][2],rso[n][3]);
                    ctx.lineTo(rso[n][4],rso[n][5]);
                    ctx.lineTo(rso[n][6],rso[n][7]);
                    ctx.lineTo(rso[n][0],rso[n][1]);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.fillStyle = rso[n][8];//"rgb("+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+")";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.closePath();
                    
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(w-rso[n][0],rso[n][1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(w-rso[n][2],rso[n][3]);
                    ctx.lineTo(w-rso[n][4],rso[n][5]);
                    ctx.lineTo(w-rso[n][6],rso[n][7]);
                    ctx.lineTo(w-rso[n][0],rso[n][1]);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.fillStyle = rso[n][8];//"rgb("+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+")";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.closePath();
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            var cx = (w-carW)/2;
            var cl = false, cr = false;
            var car = _i("c1");
            var ms = 3*w/560;
            function drawCar(){
                if(cl) if(cx+carW+50 < w) cx+=ms;
                if(cr) if(cx-50 > 0) cx-=ms;
                ctx.drawImage(car,cx,h-carH,carW,carH);
            }
            
            
            var m = 0;
            var intv = setInterval(function(){
                try{
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
                maxH+=0.5;
                changedHeight = maxH*cnst1*(Math.pow(1/ratio,totalRso-1)-1);//maxH*(1-Math.pow(ratio,totalRso-5))/(1-ratio);
                if(changedHeight >= totalHeight){
                    maxH = maxHF;
                    m++;
                }
                for(var n = 0; n < totalRso; n++){
                    rso[n]=rectPoints(n,h-totalHeight+changedHeight);
                    if(m%2==0) rso[n][8] = (n%2==0) ? "#000" : "#fff";
                    else rso[n][8] = (n%2==1) ? "#000" : "#fff";
                }
                draw();
                for(var n = 0; n < trees.length; n++){
                    trees[n].draw();
                }
                
                for(var n = 0; n < coins.length; n++){
                    coins[n].draw();
                }
                
                for(var n = 0; n < cars.length; n++){
                    cars[n].draw();
                }
                
                
                drawCar();
                }catch(err){
                    
                }
                
            },10)
            //draw();
            
            //Game Control
            
            //Touch
            function getTouch(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var to = e.changedTouches[0];
                var ty = parseInt(to.clientY);
                if(ty>(h/2)){
                    cl = true;
                }
                else{
                    cr = true;
                }
            }
            function getTouchEnd(){
                cl = false;
                cr = false;
            }
            
            c.removeEventListener("touchstart",getTouch);
            c.removeEventListener("touchend",getTouchEnd);
            c.addEventListener("touchstart",getTouch);
            c.addEventListener("touchend",getTouchEnd);
            //Key..
            function getKey(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var ty = e.keyCode;
                if(ty===39){
                    cr = false;
                    cl = true;
                }
                else if(ty===37){
                    cl = false;
                    cr = true;
                }
            }
            function getKeyEnd(e){
                var ty = e.keyCode;
                if(ty === 39) cl = false;
                else if(ty === 37) cr = false;
            }
            
            document.body.removeEventListener("keydown",getKey);
            document.body.removeEventListener("keyup",getKeyEnd);
            document.body.addEventListener("keydown",getKey);
            document.body.addEventListener("keyup",getKeyEnd);
            //Accelarometre
            
            function driveCar(e){
                var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
            
                if(y > 0){
                    if(cx+carW+50 < w) cx += y*ms;
                }
                else{
                    if(cx-50 > 0) cx += y*ms;
                }
            }
            
            if(window.DeviceMotionEvent){
                window.removeEventListener("devicemotion",driveCar)
                   window.addEventListener("devicemotion",driveCar,false)
            }
            //End
        }
        ld = function(){
            if(loaded){
                document.getElementById("startPage").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.display = "block";
                loadGame();
            }
        }
        })();
        
        </script>
        <script>
          //Thanks for visiting my code
//3D Car Drive **Pure JavaScript**
//Version : 1.0.0
//Wait sometimes after hitting the run button
//This may take a few seconds to load the assets for first time
//Don't forget to put an upvote if you enjoyed the game
//If you have any feedback or suggestion...Please comment...
alert("Rotate the phone & tilt left/right to move the car.")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the CDN inside "head"
and below is the code for sound. just add your sound at "over.mp3" place the sound.play() inside the function which runs immediately after game over
the sound is working fine on my laptop.

```
      <script
        type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.2.3/howler.js">
      </script>


      var sound = new Howl({
        src: ["over.wav", "over.mp3"],
        //autoplay: true,
        // loop: true,
        html5: true,
      });


      //Touch
      function getTouch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var to = e.changedTouches[0];
        var ty = parseInt(to.clientY);
        if (ty > h / 2) {
          cl = true;
        } else {
          cr = true;
        }
      }
      function getTouchEnd() {
        // ======== DEFINED BY AnonymousCoder
        sound.play();
        // ==================================
        cl = false;
        cr = false;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple. I too have an online html car-parking game. All you have to do is use the `<audio>` element. first, use:
`<audio src="url" autoplay controls loop />`

*list of meanings below.*

- (Optional) Autoplay

autoplays the audio when page loads, but depends on browser support.

- (Optional) Controls

gives the audio controls so the user can control it.

- (Optional) Loop

repeats the audio everytime it ends.

**However, if you don't have controls, you can't use it without JavaScript:**

```html
    <audio id="myAudio">
      <source src="https://images.githubusercontent.com/85320577/126009741-eb49b99f-1ad6-4dfd-929e-c32ac55104e9.mov">
    </audio>

        <script>
        var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        function playAudio() {
        audio.play();
        }
        </script>
        <button onclick="playAudio();">Play</button>
```

you may not be able to hear the sound, because the URl source that I put in the audio isn't valid. to make the audio, simply download the file and insert the path into the "url" part of the element. Or, I use https://GitHub.com and upload a video with the sound effect and put that in the "url".

**how to upload to Github**

visit https://github.com/
[Sign up](https://github.com/signup?ref_cta=Sign%20up&ref_loc=header%20logged%20out&ref_page=%2F&source=header-home), or if you already have an account, [Sign in.](https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Fsignup%3Fref_cta%3DSign%2Bup%26ref_loc%3Dheader%2Blogged%2Bout%26ref_page%3D%252F%26source%3Dheader-home)
click *Create new repository > set it up > Issues from the menu > create new issue > upload photo > choose the sound effect file > copy the URl > Done.*

**NOTE:** There are a lot of things to do with the `<audio>` element. However, I did not provide all of them. [See the full tutorial here.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)